# VBA recordset issue

Tags: vba

Why is it that if the number in the bracket is greater than 1272, the function returns all NA value. While if the number if smaller than 1273, the function works fine.

```
Set db = OpenDatabase(DBFullName)
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM SGXIO_Database")

 Dim arr As Variant
 Dim temp As Range
 Dim counter As Variant
 Dim num As Integer

 rs.MoveLast
 counter = rs.RecordCount
 rs.MoveFirst

 'bdd is the function name
bdd = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows(1272))


Set rs = Nothing
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that `1272` ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably because ADO sucks and runs into all sorts of memory limits you wouldn't expect. You could probably solve your problem by chunking it. Just process 1000 records at a time. Use the second parameter for GetRows to tell it where you last left off. http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_rs_getrows.asp